# Printing SQL Query in unix

Tags: unix, ksh

I need to run SQL Query in unix and print the output. After running, output printed differently.

My code:

```
i_dept=30

emp_list=`sqlplus -s SCOTT/tiger@//YourIP:1521/orcl <<END
set pagesize 0 feedback off verify off heading off echo off
select ename,dept

  from emp where deptno=$i_dept;
exit;
END`

# print all employee names using for loop
echo "List of Employees in the department $i_dept."
for empname in ${emp_list}
do
  echo $empname
done
```

Output:

```
Ajith
Marketing
Kumar
Marketing
```

But I want output like below

```
Ajith Marketing
Kumar Marketing
```

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the contents of `$emp_list` look like:

```
$ echo "${emp_list}"
Ajith Marketing
Kumar Marketing
```

We can use a `while` loop to parse `$emp_list` by line:

```
while read -r empname
do
    echo "${empname}"
done <<< "${emp_list}"
```

Which generates:

```
Ajith Marketing
Kumar Marketing
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need a loop when you quote your variable

```
echo "${emp_list}"
```